# An App to receive broadcasting from an IP Camera

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to build an own simple App on android studio, which let you 
receive a video stream from your Known Ip Adress WiFi Camera,

There are plenty of apps on the strore which accomplish that goal, (already tested), but what i want is a simple surfaceView android app Code which connects to the IP camera and gets the video Stream, so i can modified how i want.
I have searched the Internet and found plenty of codes or similiar apps but many of them unuseful and unclear,

i tried this code 
https://ijoshsmith.com/2014/01/25/video-streaming-from-an-ip-camera-to-an-android-phone/
  it compiled with no error but i have no connection after starting the App.. 
Only have a black Screen

although Username , password and ip adress of the camera are correct , 
anyone has an idea and can provide such an app ?!
thank you

Comment: There is no universal definition of "IP camera". There are many possible protocols and media formats that an "IP camera" might use. We cannot help you, in the scope of a single Stack Overflow question, connect to an arbitrary "IP camera" over all possible protocols and for all possible media formats.

Comment: Ok fair enough, maybe i was not clear with the question.

Comment: Ok fair enough, maybe i was not clear with the question.I have this camera (VIVOTEK FD8169A)which is powerded and connected to the same local Network (WIFI) as my Mobile phone,On the phone side, i can get a stream of the Video by downloading an app from the play store ( there are many- i used i viewer)

Comment: So what i need to do is to write an own app to get this Video Stream on my android device. only 3 things i needed to get connected with the Store app are: IP adress (camera)- username and password (camera)..From these three things an adroid app developper could assume on what protocol the camera is working  ,, any guess ?